# Error 422 Uploading files with laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-livewire, http-status-code-422

I am trying to upload images to S3 using laravel livewire file upload, everything works fine in development, but after deployment on staging or production, I still can upload some images but others ( mostly taken with Iphone ) are giving 422 error, I can upload them after cropping them. How can I solve this issue? I am using Heroku.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR0lM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5hF4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this by adding FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=s3 into config vars in productions.